# Cannot change permissions in symlinked dropbox directory in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, symbolic-link, chmod

Title pretty much says it all, but here's what I'm doing...

`ls -l` produces this...

```
drwx------ 1 brian brian 4096 2010-12-28 14:19 foldername
-rw------- 1 brian brian    0 2010-12-28 15:54 index.html
```

after typing something like `chmod o=rx index.html` the output of `ls -l` is the same. This happens whether or not I'm in the original location or the symlink location. However, as a further twist, the output of `chmod -v o=rx index.html` is the following:

```
mode of `index.html' changed to 0605 (rw----r-x)
```

The location is also being symlinked to by apache. What's going on with my permissions?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you properly set up the directory permissions for symlinking in your conf file?